# PSCustomObject only shows last value written

Tags: arrays, powershell, pscustomobject

New Powershell developer here. I am using the following code to compare the contents of 2 arrays and write values to a third array. The third array is updated within the inner of a nested For loop. The first loop looks at each of an array's values, and for each value in the first array loops through the second array until it finds a match. When it does, the if statement is true and that's where the PSCustomObject is updated with values from both the first and second arrays.

The logic seems to work fine in finding matches. The problem I am having is that the PSCustomObject always contains only a single row of final values even though the IF statement has been true three times and the array should contain three rows. It's as if every update of the PSCustomObject is overwriting the previous results. So 2 questions: Is this an appropriate use of PSCustomObject, and if so, what am I doing wrong?

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {
    # Output the current item
    $cfID = $array[$i].substring(65, 16)
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt $slotnames.length; $j++) {
        if ($slotnames[$j].deviceID.substring(22, 16) -eq $cfID) {
            $result = [pscustomobject]@{
                result1 = $SlotNames[$j].deviceID
                result2 = $SlotNames[$j].Location
                result3 = $array[$i].substring(1, 19)
            }
            break
        } 
        else {
            write-host 'No match!'
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: What third array? You only ever assign each individual results object to `$result`, thus overwriting the previous one on each iteration

Comment: Put the `$result =` in the outer `for` statement: `$result = for ($i=0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++)...` to capture all objects in it (and remove that assignment in the inner loop body)

Comment: So if I'm understanding, that $result=for&c replaces the outer For. And then the three values would just be added to $results[$i] within the IF statement (i.e., no PSCustomObject)?

Comment: It doesn't _replace_ the loop, it just makes it so that any output from inside the loop ends up assigned to `$result`

Comment: I would make a hashtable in comparing two big lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply let PowerShell create the resulting array of objects for you as Matthias and Santiago already commented:

```
# capture the output objects in variable $result
$result = for ($i = 0; $i -lt $array.length; $i++) {
    $cfID = $array[$i].substring(65, 16)
    for ($j = 0; $j -lt $slotnames.length; $j++) {
        if ($slotnames[$j].deviceID.substring(22, 16) -eq $cfID) {
            # Output a new object so it gets collected in variable $result
            [pscustomobject]@{
                result1 = $SlotNames[$j].deviceID
                result2 = $SlotNames[$j].Location
                result3 = $array[$i].substring(1, 19)
            }
        } 
        else {
            Write-Host 'No match!'
        } 
    }
}
```

No need to create an array (or ArrayList) before the main loop

Comment: Both this and the approach below work, but this particular approach works better than using arrayList for this particular application because the arrayList approach writes the index of each element to the console as it adds it. This approach does not produce the arguably extraneous outputs.

Answer (score 1):

PROBLEM: You are **not** ADDING the results to the `$result` variable: you are ASSIGNING them from zero each time.

SOLUTION(updated):
add  `$result=[System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()` before the Loops
then

replace

```
$result = [pscustomobject]@{
    result1 = $SlotNames[$j].deviceID
    result2 = $SlotNames[$j].Location
    result3 = $array[$i].substring(1, 19)
}
```

with

```
$result.add([pscustomobject]@{
    result1 = $SlotNames[$j].deviceID
    result2 = $SlotNames[$j].Location
    result3 = $array[$i].substring(1, 19)
} )
```

(or `$result.insert($result.count,[pscustomobject]@{...})` if you don't want the printing of the index each addition)

ignore the strike-out part, it's wrong

<strike>The easiest way to fix this is simply changing

`$result = [pscustomobject]@{...}`

to

`$result += [pscustomobject]@{...}`</strike>

***BUT!***

A few suggestions:

1. Do not use `for()` when cycling through a collection(arrays, ArrayLists, hashtables, etc), use either `$Collection | ForEach-Object` or `$Collection.foreach()`
2. Use a `ArrayList` when you are planning to add or remove elements: regular Arrays get destroyed and recreated automagically whenever elements are changed so they are inefficient.
   You can declare them simply with `$result=[System.Collections.ArrayList]::new()`
   This way you can add elements just with `$result.add($ObjectToAdd)`
   You can still access the single elements with the usual `$result[$index]`

   In general, it's better to limit the use of Arrays to fixed-sized, small-sized cases.

Comment: Thanks! Going for the easy fix first, I can't get += to work, I get: Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSObject] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.

Comment: Updated the answer, sorry for the confusion

Comment: No problem! The updated version works like a charm. Thanks for your help and the pointers as well. Is there a book or other resource you'd recommend for a beginner? The online Powershell help covers options well but leaves  a lot to be desired in practical applications.

Comment: Windows Powershell Step by Step by Ed Wilson helped me learn Powershell.  The 3rd edition covers version 5.0.  You can buy it online.  I downloaded the free PDF version, but I don't think that's available any more.

Comment: One extra note: I favor using `.Count` as index when using `.Insert()`, as it insert the most recent object at the end of the list exactly like using `.Add()`.    

An alternative is to use `0` instead of `.Count`: it results in a "reverse" List with the most recent addition at the start; if that's not a deal-breaker(given you still know the structure so you can modify it I doubt that'd be the case often), it can make the code a bit more readable. Plus you know in advance the exact position of the last added value even when the size of the List is unknowable beforehand.